# Writing TypeScript Definition

Tags: javascript, typescript, definition, definitelytyped

I've recently written a huge library in ECMAScript2015 which I would like to write a type definition for, so that it can be used in TypeScript projects.

Let's call the lib 'myShop' for now, with the basic structure being:

```
myShop.init(params): // function
myShop.cart.goto(); // function in namespace 'cart'
myShop.info; // variable that contains trivial information
```

My question is what the best practices would be, for typing the library. For just the sake of getting autocomplete in IntelliJ, there are many ways that seem to work.

My approach so far looks like this:

```
declare module myShop {

    function init(param:List<string>): Promise;

    var cart: ICart;

    var info: Object;
}

interface ICart {

    goto(): void;

}
```

Any tips for improvement? Is an interface for 'cart' correct? Should it rather be a module?

Thank you in advance!